# VMWare Fusion - DHCP Server on Windows 2012

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012, vmware-fusion

I have two virtual machines in `VMWare fusion:`

```
Windows Server 2012 - running DHCPServer installed via (Install-WindowsFeature DHCP)
Windows 10 - Shutdown, prepared with Sysprep
```

Both VM's are using `Share with my Mac` under network adapter settings.

When booting the Windows 10 VM and pressing `F12` for network boot, a IP address is not assigned via `DHCP`.

I need to assign an IP address to capture an image using `Windows Deployment Services`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the IPv4 interface was not configured to use a static IP address. `DHCPServer` was not happy with dynamic addressing.